# how to move (horinzontal verse) a div child in div parent whit jquery JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a question:
I Have 2 div:

div parent (element_two) and div child (slider_content). The width of "slider_content is bigger than the "element_two"

html:

```
<div class= "element_two">

      <div class= "slider_content" id="slider_content">

        <div class="thumb"><img src="img/imagesCarousel.jpeg" class="img_slide"></div>
        <div class="thumb"><img src="img/imagesCarousel2.jpeg" class="img_slide"></div>
        <div class="thumb"><img src="img/imagesCarousel3.jpeg" class="img_slide"></div>
        <div class="thumb"><img src="img/imagesCarousel4.jpeg" class="img_slide"></div>
        <div class="thumb"><img src="img/imagesCarousel5.jpeg" class="img_slide"></div>
        <div class="thumb"><img src="img/imagesCarousel6.jpeg" class="img_slide"></div>
        <div class="thumb"><img src="img/imagesCarousel7.jpeg" class="img_slide"></div>
      </div>

    </div>
```

css:

```
    .element_two{
         position: relative;
         overflow: hidden;
         width: 100%;



         .slider_content{
             height: 161px;
             white-space: nowrap;
         }
}
```

now, using Jquery metodh, I try to move "slider_content" respect to "element_two".

Somebody can help me?

Comment: share the whole code

Comment: change the `scrollLeft` property or set `position: absolute` on `.slider_content` and then use `left`property